# Locating existing records

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record, ip-address

In order to reduce redundancy in my app, I have added the method `self.find_or_keep(object)` to many of my models in order to find existing records with the same values, so I can reference the already existing ones instead of creating new records. Basically, this method checks most attributes for equality between two objects; `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` are always excluded for obvious reasons.

```
class IPv4 < ActiveRecord::Base
  # returns its param or an already existing record
  def self.find_or_keep(ipv4)
    # create new object in memory, if param is a Hash
    ipv4 = IPv4.new(ipv4) if ipv4.is_a?(Hash)
    return (entry = IPv4.find_by(address: ipv4.address, subnetmask: ipv4.subnetmask)) ? entry : ipv4
  end
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  # returns its param or an already existing record
  def self.find_or_keep(service)
    # create new object in memory, if param is a Hash
    service = Service.new(service) if service.is_a?(Hash)
    return (entry = Service.find_by(protocol: service.protocol, port_from: service.port_from, port_to: service.port_to)) ? entry : service
  end
end
```

As you can see, it's not very DRY. The problem here is that the method each time has to check for different parameters, so I have to rewrite the `find_by` every time I want to use the method in another class. What I have in mind for DRYing it up is something like this:

> ```
> class IPv4 < ActiveRecord::Base
>   implement_find_or_keep_with(:address, :subnetmask)
> end
>
> class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
>   implement_find_or_keep_with(:protocol, :port_from, :port_to)
> end
>
> class ActiveRecord::Base
>   # whatever is need
> end
> ```

Is something like this possible? If so, how would I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should do exactly what you want:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_or_keep_with(*args, &block)
    define_method(:find_or_keep) do |*find_or_keep_args|
      params = args.collect {|arg| [arg, object.send(arg)] }.to_h
      if block_given?
        yield(params, *find_or_keep_args)
      else
        object = find_or_keep_args.first
        find_by(params) || object
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I haven't tested the code, it may be broken, but the basic idea is there.  The class method dynamically creates the `find_or_create` method based on the attribute (as symbols or strings) that you pass in.

Notice the `block_given?`? If you want to define a custom implementation of `find_or_keep` then you can do so by:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  find_or_keep_with(:protocol, :port_from, :port_to) do |params, object, *args|
    # do you custom find_or_keep implementation here
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Very helpful answer. I modified the code a little and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Rails already has a built-in mechanism for doing this with the `first_or_initialize` method within [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize).

As an example, you can perform the following

```
Service.where(protocol: params[:protocol], port_from: params[:port_from], port_to: params[:port_to]).first_or_initialize
```

This will try and find a service with the given attributes OR initialize a new object with those attributes set if it can't find it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that method before. The thing is, I must use objects, that are already initialized. For example, for creating a Service-Object, there is one input for **protocol** and one input called **portrange**, which is an **attr_accessor** and is converted into **port_from** and **port_to** via overloading the **portrange=(str)** (for example "range 1 2" becomes port_from: 1, port_to: 2) method. That means, the object must be initialized before performing the query.

Comment: I don't understand, your `find_or_keep` method internally uses `find_by` which will require a separate `:port_from` and `:port_to` to perform the query - this isn't any different.

Comment: But I can't make use of `first_or_initialize`, or am I being stupid? Since `find_or_keep` either expects an initialized Object of that class or a hash for initializing an Object. So, when the Object is initialized, the `port_from` and `port_to` are automatically set by the overloaded `portrange=(str)`. Before it's initialized I do not know what `port_from` and `port_to` are, so I can't `Service.where([anything with port_from or port_to]).first_or_initialize`. And after it has been initialized I can't use `first_or_initialize` on the already initialized Object.

Comment: I see what you mean - yeah in that case you would either need to deconstruct `port_range` into its constituent parts before making the call, or wrap in a factory method like you're currently doing.